# iAd not showing up in an app approved by the apple

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iad

I went on to iTunes connect iAd section. It says my app is receiving live ads but in reality when I open my app it is not showing ads at all. And it has been more than a week now since Apple approved my app. I am really frustrated can anyone help me.

Comment: can you show some code you used to show ads

Comment: iAd is approved separately and they are no longer accepting new Apps into iAd as they are shutting it down on June 30th, 2016.  So unless your app has previously been approved for iAd you probably won't see any ads.  https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a  (Or do you mean you've been specifically approved for iAd a week ago which would be interesting to know given the news above?)

Comment: @RoryO'Bryan my app got approved about 2 weeks ago, could that be the reason my app not showing any ads?

Comment: Sounds very likely, as that would be after the announcement date, (You could try contacting them for a final confirmation, if they confirmed that iAd is shutting down that would be useful news for other developers. A lot of us still can't quite believe they've shut iAd down and just posted that tiny announcement I linked to above!!! )